# ¿Hay que decir "Hubo sol ayer" o "Hay sol ayer"?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, conjugación, tiempo-meteorológico

No soy hablante nativo, entonces no sé cuál es correcto.

Busqué una solución aquí pero no la encontré.

Y sé lo raro que es, pero nunca he visto o escuchado a una persona hablar sobre el clima del pasado en español.

¿Hay que decir "Hubo sol ayer" o "Hay sol ayer"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En español se usa el verbo *hacer* con los fenómenos atmosféricos que no tienen verbo propio: *hacer sol*, *hacer viento, hacer frío* y otros (en contraposición a *llover*, *nevar* y otros). Luego la expresión que buscas es:

> Ayer **hizo** sol.

Comment: Bueno, hay situaciones en que se podría decir *Ayer hacía sol* también.

Comment: Si alguien dijera que "ayer hubo sol", ¿significaría esto que el gran globo de plasma existió ayer pero ahora no existe?